# What does "late challenge" mean in football (soccer) context

Tags: word-meaning

What does "late challenge" mean in football (soccer) context?

62' Lewis Montsma is booked for a late **challenge** on Troy Parrott.

Comment: Parrott had already passed the ball when he was tackled. He was no longer in possession. Tackling someone who's not in possession is an infringement.